# Does Embarcadero RAD Studio / FireMonkey work with XCode 5?

Tags: xcode, delphi, c++builder, firemonkey, c++builder-xe5

Now that XCode 5 has been officially released, and I am being prompted by the App Store to upgrade to XCode 5, does anybody know if there are any problems using it with RAD Studio XE5/FireMonkey to develop Mac and iOS applications?

Also, since XCode 5 supports iOS 7, are there any problems developing for iOS 7 using RAD Studio XE5/FireMonkey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested Delphi XE5 with XCode 5 this week, but only with the simulator. It all works as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Bart van Dijk's answer, I went ahead and updated to Xcode 5.  I can confirm that I was able to compile and run a simple FireMonkey mobile app on both the iPhone simulator and also on a real iPad.

Also, I created a simple FireMonkey desktop app, and built and ran it on both Win32 and Max OS X 10.8.5 with no problem, and no appreciable difference from with Xcode 4.6.3

I had a little trouble updating Xcode. When the update to Xcode initially was installed, it kept crashing every time I tried to start it.  The console app said that the crash log was saved in myusersfolder/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Xcode_2013-09-27-16245...

That crash log said "The bundle \U201cIDERepositoryViewer\U201d couldn\U2019t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.\".  So, I went to Xcode/Contents/Plugins, found the file for IDERepositoryViewer, and renamed it by adding an "X" after IDERepositoryViewer.  After that, Xcode started up without problem.  I re-downloaded the Command Line Tools, and everything else seemed to work.

Of course, that doesn't guarantee that there won't be other problems, but so far, Xcode 5 seems to work with XE5 for iOS and Mac apps.

EDIT:  Embarcadero has posted info about an update to cover iOS 7 at http://blogs.embarcadero.com/sarinadupont/2013/09/19/start-building-ios-7-apps-today and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Using_the_iOS_7_Update_for_XE5